# Apportioning neighborhoods and census tracts - ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, census, apportion

I have a census tract shapefile and a neighborhood shapefile, and the end goal is to analyze vulnerable populations within each neighborhood using the data from the census tracts. Currently some of the census tracts overlap in to other neighborhoods, which I assume would lead to inaccurate results. I assume I need to apportion the neighborhood shapefile to the census tract in order to correctly analyze neighborhoods and particular vulnerable populations. I have seen a previous post on here titled [Apportioning Neighborhood Information to Census Tracts using ArcGIS desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104219/apportioning-neighborhood-information-to-census-tracts-using-arcgis-desktop). A user described how to do it, but have been unsuccessful with these directions.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so the best way to help us help you is to include the exact version of software in use, the specific methodology you attempted, and detail the exact errors or difficulty encountered. Where possible, you should include the exact URL to the question you are referencing.

Comment: Where did those instructions cease to do what they said that they would?  In other words, precisely what did you try and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate density (population per unit area), you would be able to find apportion  of your neighbourhoods based on the census tracts. If you create a density field and calculate as **population / tract area**, you can use this with Tabulate Intersection (or Intersect) tool. Then you can find each neighbourhood parts' (applicable to neighbourhoods traversing more than one tract) population by **density * part area**. Finally, by using Summary Statistics tool, you can SUM up each parts population for your neighbourhood.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. [Make Feature Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm), with ratio policy on population field:

> When Use Ratio Policy is enabled, whenever a feature in an overlay
> operation is split, the attributes of the resulting features are a
> ratio of the attribute value of the input feature. The output value is
> based on the ratio in which the input feature geometry was divided.
> For example, if the input geometry was divided equally, each new
> feature's attribute value is assigned one-half of the value of the
> input feature's attribute value. Use Ratio Policy only applies to
> numeric field types.

2. Then use the output layer as input to Intersect, Clip, or whatever overlay analysis you need.

The population with be split accourding to how the polygons are split.