# R library or tool to do spatial apportionment

Tags: r, union, intersect

Please tell me there is a package to do spatial apportionment. I find [spReapportion](https://github.com/joelgombin/spReapportion) on GitHub that's 7 years old and [this tutorial](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6577_3b66f8d8f4984fb2807e91224defa854.html), which was made with R 3.0.1 (May 2013). I'm trying to script the equivalent of ArcGIS geoprocessing 'Union', and it's a hassle which requires:

1. Import both shapefiles
2. Project both to a common projection
3. Intersect + spatial difference to get two output files
4. Bind the intersect and spatial difference together to get a union'd file.
5. Join the data back to the 'union'd file (Since intersect & spatial difference drop most variables) which introduce's NA's if you full_join.
6. Calculate the area of union'd file polygons.
7. Estimate the ratio of each polygon's new area to old area
8. Multiply the ratio by your variable of interest

In ArcGIS, steps 3,4,5 are just the geoprocessing 'union' command. ([Description of full procedure using ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104219/apportioning-neighborhood-information-to-census-tracts-using-arcgis-desktop))

Comment: If you can rewrite your question with some sample data then I think we could get into this, the problem with that tutorial is that most of those packages are deprecated now, and you should be using the `sf` package which gives you functions like `st_intersection` and `st_union` etc for doing spatial operations. Read https://r.geocompx.org/ or similar and try and update us?

Comment: Have you contacted the package maintainer to see if there is any intention of updating the package/function to leverage new spatial classes and packages? In looking at the code for `spReapportion`, it would not be all that difficult to convert calls to sp and rgeos to sf. It is fairly easy to figure the corresponding sf functions eg., `rgeos::gUnion` is `sf::st_union`. Mostly it would be removing slot calls `x@data`. You may have to also address bracket indexes for subsetting based on column name.